# How can I make a JavaScript synchronous call to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

I have a method that returns initialization data. It first checks the sessionStorage. If it doesn't find the data there, it makes a call to the server to get the data. Here's the code:

```
function getInitializationData() {

// Check local storage (cache) prior to making a server call.
// Assume HTML 5 browser because this is an Intranet application.
if (!sessionStorage.getItem("initialData")) {

    // The browser doesn't have the initialization data,
    // so the client will call the server to get the data.
    // Note: the initialization data is complex but 
    // HTML 5 storage only stores strings. Thus, the
    // code has to convert into a string prior to storage.
    $.ajax({
        url: "../initialization.x",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 10000,
        error: handleError,
        success: function(data) { sessionStorage.setItem("initialData", JSON.stringify(data)); } 
    });
}

// convert the string back to a complex object
return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("initialData"));
}
```

The problem is that the success function almost always gets executed after the method returns. How can I make the server call synchronous such that the success function must execute prior to the return statement of the getInitializationData method?

Comment: This question gets asked every day... you could make it synchronous, but it's generally a bad idea. Make  `getInitializationData` accept a callback or look into deferred objects (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Gonna write a canonical question/answer now, because at some point it's enough...

Comment: have you ever read the jQuery API? what about `async:false`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ -- the first result from Googling "jquery ajax synchronized"

Comment: Ironic the amount of questions the OPs have to bypass while just writing the initial question, and blatant disregard of the list to the right. ;p

Comment: You can add `async: false`to your options in the `$.ajax` call and this will do the trick. The property is deprecated however and may notbe supported in future versions.

Comment: Duplicates of async confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11346691/710446 (nearly exact), http://stackoverflow.com/q/13972243/710446 (about IndexedDB rather than Ajax)

Comment: I wonder who upvoted the question :/

Comment: OK; I will try to determine how to make this work with a callback. As Felix Kling and War10ck pointed out, the async option is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Use **`async: false`**

```
function getInitializationData() {

// Check local storage (cache) prior to making a server call.
// Assume HTML 5 browser because this is an Intranet application.
if (!sessionStorage.getItem("initialData")) {

    // The browser doesn't have the initialization data,
    // so the client will call the server to get the data.
    // Note: the initialization data is complex but 
    // HTML 5 storage only stores strings. Thus, the
    // code has to convert into a string prior to storage.
    $.ajax({
        url: "../initialization.x",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 10000,
        async: false,
        error: handleError,
        success: function(data) { sessionStorage.setItem("initialData", JSON.stringify(data)); } 
    });
}

// convert the string back to a complex object
return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("initialData"));
}
```

Comment: @Dirty-flow oh come on... not everyone knows that. Dude wantz sum pointz!

Comment: @Dirty-flow: tons of questions each day are closed and these types of basic questions are asked each day. Thats does not mean you do not answer when you encounter one such question.